# IMCE with Amazon S3 loads images very very slow

Tags: 7, files, wysiwyg, performance

I am using D7 with [Amazon s3](https://www.drupal.org/project/amazons3), [imce](https://www.drupal.org/project/imce), [imce filefield](https://www.drupal.org/project/imce_filefield) module to upload images through [CKEditor](https://www.drupal.org/project/ckeditor). And when I clicked on image upload button in CKEditor it is taking around 3-5 minutes to load the CKEditor popup.

Can we do something about to improve performance, or am I missing any settings, please suggest.

Using Amazon EC2 - Virtual Server Hosting, memcache.

Comment: First step: profile your site with XHProf or XDebug to know where the bottleneck is at. Without knowing the bottleneck, one can only guess at what's causing the problem, and what (if any) setting might magically remove the bottleneck.

Comment: Which version of Amazon s3 module are you using? Have you applied any patches from the module issue queue? Are you sure your settings are correct (server & Drupal)?

Comment: I am using 7.x-1.1 version, and no patches were applied.